# LIBCURL error in VS2017 C++ :: error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_init

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, static-libraries, libcurl, unresolved-external

I compiled CURL for windows to use in VS2017 as 
[shown in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wjNyT5PhNvI)

Also i have defined CURL_STATICLIB in preprocessor in C/C++ configuration properties.

Actual project properties is as 
[image: Shown in this image below]

But it get below unresolved symbol errors for LIBCURL only

```
1>mainfile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_init
1>mainfile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_setopt
1>mainfile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_perform
1>mainfile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _curl_easy_cleanup
```

Please help in resolving , it 5 hrs i have been trying to remove this :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Did you actually add the library to the additional libraries area in the project that you have not shown? You can also use `#pragma comment(lib, "libraryname")` in a cpp file assuming you have added the directory it is in to the library directories.

Comment: Below is already added
#ifdef _DEBUG
#      pragma comment(lib, "..\\curl\\libcurl_a_debug.lib")
#else
#      pragma comment(lib, "..\\curl\\libcurl_a.lib")
#endif